# Ruby Variables not working

Tags: ruby, instantiation, instance-variables

I am having trouble incrementing a variable. This seems very trivial and easy but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I have a program moving a robot about a grid and it's fully working. I would now just like to count how many moves he makes.

Here is my code:

```
Class Robot

 @counter = 0
 def move
  @counter +=1
 end

 def print
  puts "Hurray the Markov chain has worked in #{@counter}"
 end
```

I get an error saying undefined method '+' operator. I have also tried

```
@counter = @counter + 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instance variables in Ruby don't work like you're using them; you're making a class instance variable in the line above the `move` method, then using an instance variable in the two instance methods.

Comment: Here you initialize a class instance variable `@counter` to zero, then attempt to increment an uninitialized instance variable with the same name. These variables are as different from one another as would be `@night` and `@day` (but can coexist with the same name). As the instance variable has not been initialized when you attempt to increment it, it has the value `nil`. `nil` is an instance of `NilClass`, and the latter has no method `+` (needed for `+=`); hence the exception being raised.  @jstim shows you a common way to initialize an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Classes are executable code. Setting instance variables must generally be done within an instance method. Initialization is invoked by the #new method, which is created when you define "initialize" within your class.

### Initializing Instance Variables for Robot#new

For example:

```
class Robot
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def move
    @counter += 1
  end

  def print
    puts "Hurray the Markov chain has worked in #{@counter}"
  end
end

robot = Robot.new
robot.move
robot.print
```

will print what you expect:

> Hurray the Markov chain has worked in 1

### Coding Robot Without an Explicit Initializer

Coding is often a matter of style, and how you code something depends not only on what you're trying to do, but also on what you're trying to communicate. In this case, you could rewrite your class without an explicit initializer by ensuring that *@counter* is set to zero before you attempt to increment it. For example:

```
def move
  @counter.to_i.succ
end
```

This will ensure that if *@counter* is nil, it will be converted to an integer (in this case, zero) and then incremented. This might seem a bit "magical" to some folks, so you might also see people being more explicit with nil guards:

```
def move
  @counter ||= 0
  @counter  += 1
end
```

If *@counter* is nil or false, it is assigned the value of zero. This ensures that you'll be able to invoke numeric methods on its value.

Comment: For the sake of discussion: 1) I agree that the `.to_i` is a little magical, since it relies on knowing that unassigned instance variables return nil instead of blowing up, and that `to_i` turns `nil` into 0. 2) Adding a nil check into the `move` method gives it two responsibilities though, instead of just one (moving the robot). Leaving it in the initializer leaves the defaulting behavior in an expected location for setting up the object with an intelligent default, and also keeps the `move` method to a single responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>your `@counter` variable is nil because it is not getting set on line 3.</strike>

As tomsoft pointed out, the variable is actually defined, but it is defined on the class, and not an instance of the class (an individual Robot).

To define the variable on an instance of the class, you need to initialize the `@counter` variable in an initializer method.

```
class Robot
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def move
    @counter +=1
  end

  def print
    puts "Hurray the Markov chain has worked in #{@counter}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you define it is that @counter become a class variable, and not an instance variable.

```
class Robot
   @counter=0  # you are in class definition, not instance
   def self.print_counter
      puts @counter
   end
end
Robot.print_counter
```

returns

```
0
```

The only option is to define it in the initializer method

```
class Robot
  def initialize
     @counter=0
 end
end
```

Comment: No, a class variable would be `@@counter`.

Comment: not really, you can define a class variable using @counter but this variable will only by visible at the class level, not the instance level

Comment: @tomsoft, Your terminology has nothing to do with ruby.  If you want to converse with fellow rubyists, you have to learn the ruby terminology, and in ruby there is a difference between a *class variable* (@@x) and a *class instance variable* (@x defined in the class scope).

Comment: @tomsoft That would be a "class instance variable," as it's only visible within the *instance* of the class object. Try `class Foo; @bar = 1; end; Foo.instance_variables` to get the point.